CoreML stops when app transitions foreground to background
I am making CoreML predictions using an ActivityClassifier model. The model works and makes valid predictions, but I am experiencing an issue. When the PredictorTask is started in the foreground and the app goes to the background, it stops making new predictions and outputs old predictions. Here is an example of the debug output:
// starts from foreground
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 82.27%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 80.18%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.66%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.66%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 78.62%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 73.88%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 80.82%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 75.10%. Attempted 1 times.
// transitions from foreground to background
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.08%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.08%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.08%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.08%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.08%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.08%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.08%. Attempted 1 times.
Predicted: No Activity with confidence: 79.08%. Attempted 1 times.

As you can see, the prediction is stuck at the same confidence level once the app goes to the background. The same issue occurs vice versa: when the prediction starts in the background, it makes valid new predictions until the app transitions to the foreground. I run the predictor task using a timer like below.
class Predictor {
    let activityClassifier = try! MyActivityClassifier(configuration: .init())
    
    func makePrediction() throws -> PredictionOutput {
        var result: Result<PredictionOutput, Error>!
        motionDataQueue.sync {
            do {
                let prediction = try activityClassifier.prediction(input: predictionInput)
            } catch let error {
                result = .failure(error)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

class PredictorTask {
    let predictor = Predictor()
    private var timer: DispatchSourceTimer?
    // Semaphore for ensuring one task at a time
    private let taskSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    // Flag to indicate wheter timer is suspended to make sure we balance suspended timer with resume
    private var isTimerSuspended = false
    
    func start() {
        timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.global())
        timer?.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: .milliseconds(500))
        timer?.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
            // Try to decrement semaphore. If it's already 0 (another task is running), this will return immediately.
            if self?.taskSemaphore.wait(timeout: .now()) == .success {
                self?.performTask()
            }
        }
        
        timer?.resume()
    }
    
    func pause() {
        guard !isTimerSuspended else { return }
        timer?.suspend()
        isTimerSuspended = true
    }

    func resume() {
        guard isTimerSuspended else { return }
        timer?.resume()
        isTimerSuspended = false
    }

    func stop() {
        if isTimerSuspended {
            timer?.resume()
            isTimerSuspended = false
        }
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = nil
    }

    private func performTask() {
        // Defer the signal, so it's called no matter how we exit the function
        defer {
            taskSemaphore.signal()
        }
        
        do {
            let prediction = try predictor.makePrediction()
            // ...
            print("Predicted: \(predictedLabel) with confidence: \(String(format: "%.2f", predictedConfidence * 100))%. Attempted \(String(predictionAttempt)) times. ")
            
        } catch {
            print("Error making prediction: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

Another behavior I observed is that once the app returns to the scene where the prediction started (i.e., foreground), the task timer cannot be canceled.
Any ideas on what might be happening here?

Unless you are using a valid Background Mode this is expected behavior. Apps don’t last long in the background
